# Why does this interface hard cast seem to work?

Tags: delphi

A Delphi mantra I grew up with is:

["You should never ever, hard type cast an interface."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755089/2306907) This probably [wont work](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2005/01/interface-to-interface-casts.html).

Now I have to decide to refactor the following code:

```
type
    IFoo = interface
    end;

    TIFoo = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo)
    end;

    IFooList = interface
        function GetItem(I: Integer): IFoo;
        procedure AddItem(AItem: IFoo);
    end;

    TIFooList = class(TInterfaceList, IFooList)
    protected
        function GetItem(I: Integer): IFoo;
        procedure AddItem(AItem: IFoo);
    end;


function TIFooList.GetItem(I: Integer): IFoo;
begin
    Result := IFoo(Items[I]);    // <----- ???
end;

procedure TIFooList.AddItem(AItem: IFoo);
begin
    Add(AItem);
end;
```

This interface hard cast has been running a bazillion times for years without ever causing problems. Why? Pure Chance? Or does exist an exception to the rule?

**Edit:**
I should have added: In the code base all `IFoo` instances are implemented by `TIFoo`.

Comment: Why am I asking? Before investing time to refactor I need arguments to touch perfectly running code. And this kind of code is suggested on [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228737/is-delphi-generic-tinterfacelist-possible) [places](https://www.delphipraxis.net/1150312-post13.html) too. The argument here is: if it is guaranteed, that the added interface is of type IFoo, then it is not really a cast.

Comment: Yes, this is down to chance. It's not hard to create examples where such casts fail. Get rid of these casts and do them properly.

Comment: What's the type of `Items[I]`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is this still true, if all added instances are implemented by `TIFoo`? Then I would like to see such an example.

Comment: @Olivier `Items[I]` is of type `IInterface`. It is inherited from `TInterfaceList`: `property Items[Index: Integer]: IInterface read Get write Put; default;`

Comment: If the interface is only ever implemented by one class, and your cast happens to work for such a class then, well, the cast works. But the problems occur when you consider interfaces implemented in arbitrary fashion. Why are you averse to doing the right thing? What is scaring you? I mean, why are you even having to cast at all? Why aren't you using `TList<IFoo>`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not averse to doing the right thing. I will change the code sooner or later. But if under the given conditions the code is guaranteed to run, there is no need to hurry. I am not speaking about a single class. This pattern is used in several units. Some of this code is used in areas that might be time critical. So I am a little bit worried the right thing might affect execution speed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I really would appreaciate to have [a drop-in replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228737/is-delphi-generic-tinterfacelist-possible), but `TList<IFoo>` wont do, because `IFooList` is used as an interface.

Comment: I don't think execution speed is going to be an issue. And you can easily graft reference counting life time management onto the generic list. Then there'd be no need for runtime casts. Kind of the whole point of generics.

Comment: It does not matter who implements what. If you can only ever put `IFoo` into the list (via `AddItem`) then its guaranteed that any interface in that list is in fact an `IFoo`. It is exactly what Hallvard wrote in his article on "interface hard-casts": "You are basically telling the compiler that the interface reference on the right side already contains a reference of the cast-to interface type"

Comment: @StefanGlienke  Yes, this was the intention of the question: Is the hard cast save, if all items of the list were added via `AddItem(IFoo)`? The described construct was used in different places to circumvent the [missing generic TInterfaceList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228737/is-delphi-generic-tinterfacelist-possible).

Comment: @StefanGlienke Your reasoning sounds logical. Would you like to provide this as an answer? I'll accept.